# What is the role of particle と in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> ネズミだ、あれ**と**出｛で｝くわす**と**厄介｛やっかい｝なんだ

I know that と could be used as a quotative particle or it could be used to make a conditional sentence. Particle と can also mean "and" or "with". In the sentence above, I think the first と means "with", but about the second と, I am not sure if it is conditional or quotative.

What are the meaning and grammatical role of particle と in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is like "with" as you say.

Second one turns the prose behind it 「(ネズミ)と出くわす」 into a sort of condition, a "what if" or "if x".

**Think of it like so; "if X were to happen/be the case, the outcome will be Y".**

あれと出くわすと厄介なんだ / To come across (a mouse) would be worrisome.

**Some more examples using this particular structure:**

睡眠【すいみん】を十分【じゅうぶん】とらないと体【からだ】を壊す【こわす】 / If you don't sleep enough, you will become unhealthy

ちゃんとお掃除【おそうじ】しないとゴキブリが出る【でる】 / If you don't clean properly, cockroaches will appear

速く【はやく】走る【はしる】と速く【はやく】着く【つく】 / If you run quickly, you will arrive quickly

Comment: 「着く」のは「速く」じゃなくて「早く」では。。。？　（でも、英語だとどっちも quickly なの？不思議～）

Comment: @Chocolate感覚的に考えると、早く：Early「朝早く、お早う」で、速く：Quickly「速度、速報」ですかね。。。この場合どっちでもいいでは？